# How can I dump pillar data, that will be send to minion

Tags: salt-stack

When I do highstate at minion, there is a strange error. I suspect, that the pillar data on the minion may not be right. Can I somehow dump the pillar data from minion?

Comment: What is the output of highstate on the minion?

Comment: It's really long ago. I've fixed the issue in the meantime using the answers below :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you said in your answer to your own question,

```
salt '*' pillar.data
```

will show all the data.  However, you have some additional useful commands:

```
salt '*' pillar.raw
```

will show the raw data as it's loaded into the `__pillar__` dict.

```
salt '*' pillar.get <key>
```

will show you the value of some key in pillar, with the ability to default to a certain value if the key doesn't exist.  (The default is super useful when you're using pillar when templating states)

Comment: data & raw commands give me same output. What would make them different?

Comment: `pillar.raw` will return the actual data on the minion at this moment, while `pillar.data` will do a limited pillar refresh and check what pillar data looks like on the master, without actually refreshing the minions' data.  Note that running a highstate will refresh the pillar.  Thus, if you've changed pillar on the master and have no refreshed (explicitly or via a highstate), the output will be different.

Comment: From Salt 0.16.2, you should use `pillar.items` *(`pillar.data` is deprecated)*. Reference: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/pillar/#viewing-minion-pillar

Comment: // , For a master-less setup, how would one view this with something like `salt-call`?

Comment: `pillar.data` and `pillar.get` work with `salt-call` as well.

Answer (score 2):

To see the pillar data

```
salt '*' pillar.data
```

It's good idea to refresh the pillar data first using

```
salt '*' saltutil.refresh_pillar
```

Answer (score 2):

Also using :

salt '*' pillar.items

Will show you all pillars node by node